# Help with a site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, site.com

I don't understand this:
I have a site that works fine when its url has "/apex/..." but when I use another link, which should be the default one that I will share at the end, it gives me an error. does anyone know why?

In this site (the external site) I can't to see the data. I have this error:

this page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')] Failing descriptor: {markup://c:accountList}

[image]

In this, we can see the data (in this site, the URL have ".../apex/.."
[image]

Because suggestions, I'll upload the HTML code:
HTML

```
<template>
<lightning-card 
    title = "XXXXxxXXXxxxxxxXXXX"
    icon-name = "action:new_group">
        <button>
            <lightning-badge
                class = "xxxxxxxx"
                label = "xxxxxxxxxx" 
                icon-name = "utility:cancel_transfer">
            </lightning-badge>
        </button>
    <div class = "slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
        <!-- Start account list -->
        <template if:true = {accounts.data}>
            <lightning-input 
                type = "search"
                onchange = {handleSearchTermChange}
                variant = "label-hidden"
                class = "slds-var-m-bottom_small"
                label = "Search"
                placeholder = "Search an account by name"
                value = {searchTerm}>
            </lightning-input>
            <lightning-layout 
                multiple-rows = "true" 
                pull-to-boundary = "small">
                <template 
                    for:each = {accounts.data} 
                    for:item = "account">
                    <lightning-layout-item 
                        key = {account.Id} 
                        size = "3" 
                        class = "slds-var-p-around_x-small">
                        <!-- Start account tile -->
                        <c-account-tile
                            account = {account}
                            onaccountview = {handleAccountView}>
                        </c-account-tile>
                        <!-- End account tile -->
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout>
            <!-- No accounts found -->
            <template if:false = {hasResults}>
                <div class = "slds-align_absolute-center slds-var-m-vertical_small">
                        Didn't found
                </div>
            </template>
        </template>
        <!-- End account list -->
        <!-- Data failed to load -->
        <template if:true = {accounts.error}>
            <div class = "slds-text-color_error">
                Error
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

Comment: None of the previous tags seemed to be appropriate. I made a best attempt to determine what an appropriate tag might be.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not post error messages (or code) only as screenshots. Text in images is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. Instead, please edit your question, copy the full error text, and paste it in the SFSE editor. For easier/better readability, most people on this site format error text as a block quote (by putting a >  in front of the text).

Comment: First thing that comes to mind from your description is a missing permission. /apex/ runs as you NOT the guest site user.

Comment: Thanks Derek for your suggestions. I'll change the tags.

Girbot, what kind of permissions I'm missing?

Comment: @Girbot can you help me? I don't know what permissions you're talking about. I have write the LWC, then I create a VF Page, where I put the the LWC. Then I create a new Site, using the VF Page as the active site home page.